# Google Sheets - Setting background color

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I'm writing an app previously held by another developer. After a certain treatment, he wanted to fill a Google Sheets file with values. Before he could start developing, he was gone, leaving me with the task to understand the google-api-client-php library.

I manage to insert values (that was a big step for me) but I would like to add a background color to certain cells. I didn't find any way to acheive this...

For now, that's how I insert values :

```
class Sheet {
    public function __construct($client) {
        $this->service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    }
    public function write($line, $newValues, $startColumn)
    {
        $values = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
        $values->setValues([    $newValues  ]); 

        $this->service->spreadsheets_values->update($this->id, $range, $values, ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED']);
    }
}
```

And I'd like to create a `colorLine()` function.

Here my first try :

```
 public function colorLine($line, $r, $g, $b, $a = 1) {
   $myRange = [
        'sheetId' => 1,
        'startRowIndex' => $line,
        'endRowIndex' => $line,
        'startColumnIndex' => 0,
        'endColumnIndex' => 1000,
    ];

    $requests = [
        new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'addConditionalFormatRule' => [
                'rule' => [
                    'ranges' => [ $myRange ],
                    'booleanRule' => [
                        'condition' => [
                            'type' => 'CUSTOM_FORMULA',
                            'values' => [ [ 'userEnteredValue' => '=1' ] ]
                        ],
                        'format' => [
                            'backgroundColor' => [ 'red' => $r, 'green' => $g, 'blue' => $b ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'index' => 1
            ]
        ])
    ];

    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
        'requests' => $requests
    ]);
    $response = $this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($this->id,
        $batchUpdateRequest);
}
```

First, I don't even *really* understand what I've written... Plus, it's saying "Invalid requests[0].addConditionalFormatRule: No grid with id: 1", but it's not that bad, I don't think it would have done what I'm looking for.

I think it would create a "conditional format", but I just want a background... This API looks very complicated for simple applications...

Anyway! If someone could help me, I would be very thankful!

Comment: Why answer your question in your question? Write it as a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Self answers are perfectly ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If you don't really care about explainations, just go to the final section :)*

That's maybe not the best solution, but at least it worked.

## The solution' explaination (TL, NR) :

### What do we need ?

1. The RGBa values we want
2. The range (sheetId, row index, columns
   index's)
3. The spreadsheet Id.

Now, how should we proceed? Well the previous source code wasn't *that bad* actually... Just need to change it a little bit :

- We don't want to create ConditionalFormats, but to update cells, so we should use the "*repeatCell*" request (I will explain why the "*repeatCell*" instead of "*updateCell*")
- [In this request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest), we can have 3 parameters :

  - the mask field (that restrict updates),
  - the range
  - the cell. That's a [CellData object](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData) that can contain a "userEnteredFormat" ([CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellFormat)) **AND NOW** you have access to the backgroundColor property!!

### Start coding :

Ok, so let's define the range :

You cannot have the "start" and "end" at the same position (so have -1 at the start, it will change only one line)

```
    $myRange = [
        'sheetId' => $sheetId,
        'startRowIndex' => $line-1,
        'endRowIndex' => $line,
        'startColumnIndex' => 0,
        'endColumnIndex' => 17,
    ];
```

Now let's define the color (each component must be between 0 and 1) :

```
    $format = [
        "backgroundColor" => [
            "red" => $r,
            "green" => $g,
            "blue" => $b,
            "alpha" => $a,
        ],
    ];
```

And that's it, we're almost ready!

We just have to tell the service that we want a "*repeatCell*" request. Do not forget the "fields" parameter. If you don't restrict the update, all the data of the cell will change, **including the text**! In this case, the path for the "fields" starts at "cell", so we just type *'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor'*. Then use the $format variable previously created.

```
    $requests = [
        new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'repeatCell' => [
                'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor',
                'range' => $myRange,
                'cell' => [
                    'userEnteredFormat' => $format,
                ],
            ],
        ])
    ];
```

OK! Done. Now include this (or these) request in the batch :

```
    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
        'requests' => $requests
    ]);
```

And at last, send the request with the service, include the speadsheet ID (`$this->id` in my case).

```
    $response = $this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($this->id,
        $batchUpdateRequest);
```

## Complete solution :

Thanks for reading, there's your solution :

```
public function colorLine($line, $r, $g, $b, $a = 1.0, $worksheetName = null)
{
    if($r > 1) $r = Tools::rescale($r, 0, 255, 0, 1);
    if($g > 1) $g = Tools::rescale($g, 0, 255, 0, 1);
    if($b > 1) $b = Tools::rescale($b, 0, 255, 0, 1);
    if($a > 1) $a = Tools::rescale($a, 0, 255, 0, 1);

    $worksheetName = ($worksheetName ? : $this->defaultWorksheet);
    $sheetId = $this->getWorksheetId($worksheetName);

    $myRange = [
        'sheetId' => $sheetId,
        'startRowIndex' => $line-1,
        'endRowIndex' => $line,
        'startColumnIndex' => 0,
        'endColumnIndex' => 17,
    ];
    $format = [
        "backgroundColor" => [
            "red" => $r,
            "green" => $g,
            "blue" => $b,
            "alpha" => $a,
        ],
    ];

    $requests = [
        new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'repeatCell' => [
                'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor',
                'range' => $myRange,
                'cell' => [
                    'userEnteredFormat' => $format,
                ],
            ],
        ])
    ];

    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
        'requests' => $requests
    ]);
    $response = $this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($this->id,
        $batchUpdateRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found a working solution for this.

```
$sheetId = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId, ['ranges' => 'worksheetname']);

//For range, end rows and end columns are not considered for updating. Index start from 0
//Here we are setting range for A3:E5 grid
$range = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$range->setSheetId($sheetId->sheets[0]->properties->sheetId);
$range->setEndRowIndex(2);
$range->setEndRowIndex(5);
$range->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$range->setEndColumnIndex(5);

//set the color value in RGBA
$color = new Google_Service_Sheets_Color();
$color->setRed($red / 255);
$color->setGreen($green / 255);
$color->setBlue($blue / 255);
$color->setAlpha($alpha);

//cellFormat is used to set different properties of a cell
$cellFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat();

//textFormat is used to set different text formats like Bold
$textFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_TextFormat();
$textFormat->setBold(true);
$cellFormat->setBackgroundColor($color);
$cellFormat->setTextFormat($textFormat);

//New cell class. Assign the cellFormat to it
$cell = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellData();
$cell->setUserEnteredFormat($cellFormat);

//repeatCell request is used to assign requests to range of cells
$repeatCell = new Google_Service_Sheets_RepeatCellRequest();
$repeatCell->setRange($range);

//Fields is used to specify which properties of a cell to update
//Here we are updating two properties. So both are specified and seperated by comma ,
$repeatCell->setFields('userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor');

//Set repeatCellrequest to the requests class
$requests = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$requests->setRepeatCell($repeatCell);

//requests are set to batchupdatespreadsheetrequest class
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($requests);

//Finally batchUpdate is called to update the format of cells
$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $batchUpdateRequest, []);
```

[For more detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86q5TMzvRqo)